# How to create this particular shape with xml in Android?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-shape

I want create one shape such as below image, but I want create this **with XML** codes (in drawable) and I **do not want** create this with **9.patch** images!
[image]

How can I create this shape with xml code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a work- around

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners 
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

Tweak the corner radius to get your upper part curved!

or overlap this oval shape to get the desired output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <!--circle filling color-->
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke
    <!--radious can define in here-->
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="2dp"
    android:topRightRadius="2dp" />
</shape>
```

But basically, this is not the correct way to do this! Use another way around, use 9 patch

Comment: thanks man, but this shape not just around top Radius!  your code is just around up corners !

Comment: tweak it bro, i don't have as opened so can't really get you the exact output!